# How to check if uploaded PDF is encrypted or not by Laravel Validation

Tags: laravel, encryption, file-upload

How to check if uploaded PDF is encrypted or not by Laravel Validation Engine. Is it possible?

Comment: OK, I can write own validator. Just tell me how to check if PDF is encrypted or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just validate the PDF header information, google for that information.

If something is encrypted it the data will look like random bytes, there will be no patterns. So if the header is correct, only a few bytes need to be checked, the PDF file is not encrypted.